# Question about an example of $(W^{\perp})^{\perp} \neq W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Let $\mathbb{R}[X]$ be a vector space endowed with an inner product $\langle p,q \rangle = \int_{0}^{1}p(x)q(x)dx$ and let $W = \{ p(x) \in \mathbb{R}[X]: p(0) = 0 \}$. Show that $W^{\perp} = \{0\}$.

It could be very simple (and intuitive), but I don't know how to show that if $\int_{0}^{1}p(x)q(x)dx =0$ for all $p(x) \in W$ then $q(x) = 0$. I was thinking about write generical expressions for p and q but when we make $p \cdot q$ it is not usefull.

Can you give me an easy way?? I mean, some hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $p(x)=xq(x)\in W$ and note that $xq^2(x)$ is continuous and non-negative in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you!! I got it

Comment: @Joãonani You are welcome ;)